# How can I make textBox gets quantity in number in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am doing one program that works like one Supermarket,and you can choose what you want to buy and you can put the quantity that you want from some product,but I don't get how to make work through textBox.

The image of the code is that :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrZql.png

Its in the Quantity textBox that when the user put some number of quantity,he will get the price of the product and in the Total appears together with the rest of the result.

Comment: Please don't make your question harder to answer than it needs to be. Don't post an "image of the code", post the **actual code** so you can let folks copy and paste it and then analyze it.

Comment: if JCheckBox is selected, Integer.parseInt((JTextField reference).getText()) * price ...

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a JTextField.

Instead you can use a `JSpinner`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html).

The section on `Detecting Spinner Changes` will help you how to use a `ChangeListener` so you can monitor when the quantity changes, then you can calculate the total amount.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use Integer.parseInt but in a try/catch block, just like this:

```
try{
    int quantity1 = Integer.parseInt(yourJTextfield.getText());
    //.......... get the other quantities here
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    // Something went wront here, the user typed a non-numeric value and this exception will be raised, show an alert for example
}
```

Comment: Or you can use the JSpinner and only number values can only ever be entered so you never need to worry about this. You can also control the range so you don't need to do any edit checking.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the content of the text box to an int.

```
int total = Integer.parseInt(textbox.getText());
```